# How to optimize javascript assets in an XCode project?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, requirejs, webkit

I have a Cocoa / Obj-C / XCode project whose primary function is to host a WebKit browser application. So there are many javascript files included in the XCode project.

What steps should I take to optimize/minify these javascript files as part of the project build (for example using RequireJS optimizer)?